# Batch file remove text after .# in variable

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to remove all characters in a variable after 1 decimal place. The text comes in as ##.####### (#=numbers) and I would like to reduce it to ##.#.

Example:
92.0762329101563
down to 92.0

I have tried:

```
set "_e=%%e" 
echo !_e! **ECHOS: 92.0762329101563** 
set "end_e=!_e:*.=!" 
echo !end_e! **ECHOS: 0762329101563**
set "end_e=!end_e:~1!" 
echo !end_e! **ECHOS: 762329101563**
call set "final_e=!!_e:!end_e!=!!" 
echo !final_e! **ECHOS: end_e**
```

I can't get the final step work. I am attempting to replace **end_e** in **_e** with nothing.
I prefer to process this in **set** if possible as I am already looping inside of two for loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, the thing that you're processing is always going to be a number and you always want to round down, right? Like even if it was 92.999, you'd still want it to be 92?

Comment: Always a number, yes. It will parse through a couple hundred of the. But 92.999 I would take to 92.9. One character after the decimal.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code, or at least the `for` loop which is generating `%%e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close with your idea to use `!!` for the outer variable and `!` for the inner variable. Unfortunately, batch won't expand `!!` in a call, but you can instead use `%%` for the outer variable and `!` for the inner variable.

```
set "_e=%%e"
echo !_e!
set "end_e=!_e:*.=!"
echo !end_e!
set "end_e=!end_e:~1!"
echo !end_e!
call set "final_e=%%_e:!end_e!=%%"
echo !final_e!
```